# Error code 3019 in mysql, how to correct?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

> Error Code: 3019. Undo Log error: No more space left over in system
>   tablespace for allocating UNDO log pages. Please add new data file to
>   the tablespace or check if filesystem is full or enable auto-extension
>   for the tablespace

Is it because the hard disk space is too low? or is it because the memory is too low?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a Tablespace, you define its size. Now the Tablespace for the Undo-Logs is full.

Tablespaces do (intentionally) not grow on their own, so having more hard disk space won't directly help. You need to explicitly increase the allocated Tablespace size (or allow Auto-Increase), to allow it to use more size of your hard disk.

Alternatively, you might want to look into why the Undo Logs are running out of space. Either there are many large open transactions (forgot a Commit?), or it was too small to start with (or both); either way you should follow up and correct it.

Comment: I am using `update table
set col=null where date is between date1 and date2`, when `date2-date1` is small enough, there is no error. So I think the problem is the case one in your answer?

Comment: Can you give a detailed guide how to `explicitly increase the allocated Tablespace size (or allow Auto-Increase)`?